# Adding to a CSV File in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm working on a project where I have to make and append a CSV file but I'm not getting the content to save to the file.
The exact instructions are:

**Using functions, create a loop to get data from user
Name
Address
City
State
Zip
Phone
Store that data in a text file, appending to the end of the file
Loop should have an option to quit before entering next set of data
The file should
Be in CSV format
Have a header line**

so far what I have is

```
cls

$csvPath = 'D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK7\List.csv'
Add-Content -path D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK7\List.csv -Value '"Name","Address","City","State","Zip","Phone"'

do{
$list = @(

$Name = Read-host 'Enter Your Name' 

$Address = Read-host 'Enter Your Address'

$City = Read-host 'Enter Your City'

$State = Read-host 'Enter Your State'

$Zip = Read-host 'Enter Your Zip'

$Phone = Read-host 'Enter Your Phone Number'
)

$Quit = Read-host 'Press "q" to exit'



$list | ForEach-Object  {
     $objResults = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name    = $Name
        Address = $Address
        City    = $City
        State  = $State
        Zip    = $Zip
        Phone  = $Phone
   
    }
    $objResults | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $csvPath -append 
}



}
while($quit -ne 'q')
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this make a difference for you?

```
Function Add-UserInfo{
cls
$csvPath = "D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK7\List.csv"


$Name = Read-host 'Enter Your Name' 
$Address = Read-host 'Enter Your Address'
$City = Read-host 'Enter Your City'
$State = Read-host 'Enter Your State'
$Zip = Read-host 'Enter Your Zip'
$Phone = Read-host 'Enter Your Phone Number'

$objResults = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name    = $Name
        Address = $Address
        City    = $City
        State  = $State
        Zip    = $Zip
        Phone  = $Phone
   
    }

$objResults | Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -NoTypeInformation -Append
Start-Sleep 2
Add-UserInfo
}
```

Add-UserInfo

Comment: It didn't have a way to quit so I added that but yes it helped a lot thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn `$objResults` into an array and then export it all at once at the end.

Also you may want to consider turning `$list` into a hashtable which will allow you to easily add it to the PSObject

```
cls

$csvPath = 'D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK7\List.csv'
Add-Content -path D:\Users\zabin\OneDrive\Desktop\ITS3410\WEEK7\List.csv -Value '"Name","Address","City","State","Zip","Phone"'

# Create an empty array
$objResults = @()

do{
# Hastable
$list = @{

  Name = $(Read-host 'Enter Your Name')
  Address = $(Read-host 'Enter Your Address')
  City = $(Read-host 'Enter Your City')
  State = $(Read-host 'Enter Your State')
  Zip = $(Read-host 'Enter Your Zip')
  Phone = $(Read-host 'Enter Your Phone Number')
}

# Append to the array
$objResults += New-Object PSObject -Property $list

$Quit = Read-host 'Press "q" to exit'

}
while($quit -ne 'q') 

# Export the array to CSV after 'q' has been pressed
$objResults | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $csvPath -append
```